# Android registerReceiver Inside runing service that waiting for AlarmManager system msg

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have running service which includes broadcast receiver .
I need the broadcast receiver to get the message from system timer clock interrupt that Alarm Manager made.
The main idea behind this is that when user close the app the service will continue listening until time interrupt happens .
I dont know why its not working ): how to do it correct please ?

Main Activity :

```
service.registerRecvierForAlarm();

Intent intent = new Intent(Send.this, SmsReciverService.class);
intent.setAction("intent_myaction_alarm");
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Send.this, 0, intent, 0);            
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pintent);
```

Service :

```
public void registerRecvierForAlarm(){

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("intent_myaction_alarm");

this.ReceiverAlarm = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("message recived");
    }
  };

this.registerReceiver(this.ReceiverAlarm,intentFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SmsReciverService` is service so you need to use `getService()` to create `PendingIntent` instead of `getBroadcast`(used for creating PendingIntent for BroadcastReceiver) to start Service using `AlarmManager` :

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Send.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

OR

if you need to fire `BroadcastReceiver` using `AlarmManager` then creating Intent by using class name which is extending `BroadcastReceiver` as second parameter to Intent constructor :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Send.this, SmsReciverBroadcast.class);
                                       ^^^^^^
intent.setAction("intent_myaction_alarm");
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Send.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: I know this but i dont want to start the service in later time , the service is alredy runing .   i need the service to listen with broadcastReceiver to the system .

Comment: @StavBodik: then Create intent using broadcastReceiver name see my edit answer

Comment: @StavBodik: but for broadcastReceiver probably you need to create Receiver by extending `BroadcastReceiver` and register in `AndroidManifest` with custom action `intent_myaction_alarm` instead of registering dynamically using `registerReceiver`

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing the problem is that my class SmsReciverBroadcast extending service , it is a serivce wich have BroadcastReceiver .

Comment: @StavBodik: ok then try it as `Intent intent = new Intent(Send.this, ReceiverAlarm.class);`

Comment: and what then ? ReceiverAlarm.class will start the service ^^ ? i need the runing service to get message from cpu clock interrupt vector to start do job .

Comment: I think i need another service only for this job.

Comment: @StavBodik: let me know what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi thanks you very much i used getService with some if's inside the service (: